# Close.app() does not work. App keeps running onto next test without closing the app

Tags: ios, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, webdriver, appium

I am doing basic automation testing for my company. I am a novice so the code is not the greatest.

I am doing a login scenario, and then the next test I want to be doing something else with the initial page (not logged in area). I don't want to have to write a script for logging out. Android automatically resets to the beginning with each start up of a new test. I am trying to use driver/browser.closeApp() to achieve this but it does not process. It gets hit but does not close the app.

**Here is the code:**

```
  after(async () => {
    await browser.closeApp()
    console.log('DID IT DO THIS?');
  });
```

**Here is the log:**

```
[0-0] 2023-09-05T20:39:07.333Z INFO webdriver: [POST] http://localhost:4723/session/c56be746-dd45-490d-91a2-2ae67f5be0e8/element/67040000-0000-0000-67F4-000000000000/click
[0-0] 2023-09-05T20:39:16.577Z INFO webdriver: COMMAND closeApp()
[0-0] 2023-09-05T20:39:16.577Z INFO webdriver: [POST] http://localhost:4723/session/c56be746-dd45-490d-91a2-2ae67f5be0e8/appium/app/close
[0-0] DID IT DO THIS?
[0-0] 2023-09-05T20:39:16.588Z INFO webdriver: COMMAND closeApp()
[0-0] 2023-09-05T20:39:16.588Z INFO webdriver: [POST] http://localhost:4723/session/c56be746-dd45-490d-91a2-2ae67f5be0e8/appium/app/close
[0-0] 2023-09-05T20:39:16.603Z INFO webdriver: COMMAND deleteSession()
[0-0] 2023-09-05T20:39:16.603Z INFO webdriver: [DELETE] http://localhost:4723/session/c56be746-dd45-490d-91a2-2ae67f5be0e8
[0-0] PASSED in ios - /tests/specs/iOS/companyOwnerSide/login_process.js
2023-09-05T20:39:16.733Z INFO @wdio/cli:launcher: Run onWorkerEnd hook
2023-09-05T20:39:16.733Z INFO @wdio/cli:launcher: Run onWorkerStart hook
2023-09-05T20:39:16.734Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: Start worker 0-1 with arg: 
[0-1] 2023-09-05T20:39:17.051Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: Run worker command: run
[0-1] RUNNING in ios - /tests/specs/iOS/companyOwnerSide/signUp_process.js
[0-1] 2023-09-05T20:39:17.290Z INFO webdriver: Initiate new session using the WebDriver protocol
[0-1] 2023-09-05T20:39:17.315Z INFO webdriver: [POST] http://localhost:4723/session
[0-1] 2023-09-05T20:39:17.315Z INFO webdriver: DATA {
[0-1]   capabilities: {
```